# Why is void keyword not used as method argument?

Tags: java, language-design

The `void` keyword is only used as a return type to indicate that a method does not return a value. 
But why can't `void` be used as a formal parameter in method definition to indicate that it does not accept any arguments, like:

```
void fun(void){
    ...
}
```

Comment: Because it isn't; what would the purpose be?

Comment: What would be the technical advantage over `void fun()`?

Comment: Note however that it's wrapper class equivalent, Void, may be used as a *generic* parameter. This is a totally different situation however.

Comment: This is actually a good question. People who downvote/closed this question probably never learn c which `(void)` and `()` are difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's unnecessary. If a method does not have arguments, specifying an empty argument set *()* is sufficient.

Answer (score 4):

I believe in C having no arguments meant it ignored any arguments given e.g. you could write `int main()` or `int main(int argc, char** argv)`  This meant when you wanted to make it clear you really meant no arguments you had to write `(void)`

In Java you have `()` to mean no arguments, so you don't need another way of saying this.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, if you want to define a method with no parameters, you simply need to have `method()`. Void doesn't explicitly mean nothing, it means no return value.

Answer (score -1):

int func(void) was a kludge introduced by Bjarne Stroustrup into C++ because int func() already meant any number of arguments in C. That problem doesn't arise in Java so introducing it would have been redundant.

Comment: No, it was the other way round - C++ redefined `()` to mean no arguments, and Java copied C++ rather than C.